# Extract first "set of rows" matching a particular condition in Spark Dataframe (Pyspark)

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a Spark DataFrame with data like below:

```
ID | UseCase
-----------------
0  | Unidentified
1  | Unidentified
2  | Unidentified
3  | Unidentified
4  | UseCase1
5  | UseCase1
6  | Unidentified
7  | Unidentified
8  | UseCase2
9  | UseCase2
10 | UseCase2
11 | Unidentified
12 | Unidentified
```

I have to extract the top 4 rows which have value `Unidentified` in column `UseCase` and do further processing with them. I don't want to get the middle and last two rows with `Unidentified` value at this point.

I want to avoid using the `ID` column as they are not fixed. The above data is just a sample.
When I use map function (after converting this to RDD) or UDFs, I end up with 8 rows in my output DataFrame (which is expected of these functions).

How can this be achieved? I am working in PySpark. I don't want to use collect on the DataFrame and get it as a list to iterate over. This would defeat the purpose of Spark. The DataFrame size can go up to 4-5 GB.

Could you please suggest how this can be done? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "the top four rows" you mean you want the first 4 when ordered by ID?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I need to get the first 'n' rows from the DataFrame which have the value of `Unidentified` under UseCase column.

Comment: yes, but what do you mean "first"? If the DataFrame is not ordered, "first" is a non-deterministic concept. Do you want the first randomly picked rows or the first rows according to some ordering rule?

Comment: I am trying to get the rows which have 'UseCase' value as 'Unidentified'. In this example, I will be extracting the first four rows and process them. Once processed, the values in 'UseCase; column will be replaced with proper UseCase (as present in 4, etc.).

Comment: Ok, so, when ordered by ID, you want to get *all* lines that have Unidentified as UseCase at the beginning, is that correct? So if the first line has a valid use case, you don't take any?

Comment: Yes. If the first line has a valid Use case then I search for the row which has the value 'Unidentifed' and take the set of rows from there. In the  example I gave in my original question, if the rows with ID: 0 to 5 have all valid Use Cases then I have to extract Row 6 and 7 (which have 'Unidentified' in them) and process these rows.

Comment: In this case, it's easier (and faster) to get all Unidentified rows and process at once. If you really want to apply your rule, you probably need to do some windowing and grouping.

Comment: Hi @RamKumarV curious how you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Just do a filter and a limit. The following code is Scala, but you'll understand the point.

Assume your dataframe is called df, then:

```
df.filter($"UseCase"==="Unidentified").limit(4).collect()
```